# How to convert (n,) matrix to (1,n) matrix in python

Tags: python

How to convert (n,) matrix to (1,n) numpy matrix in python

I tried using transpose by it makes it into (n,1) , which is not what I am looking for

Comment: you have to provide an input & expected output, else it's too broad.

Comment: By "matrix", do you mean a `numpy` matrix or just a list of lists?

Comment: @hlt yes it is numpy matrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = x[:,None].T
```

This worked for me

Comment: First of all you are using nd arrays, not matrices, that introduces confusion. Second, this is a dirty way of doing things and by that I mean all of the workaournds I've seen so far are nasty and far from linear algebra.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're referring to Numpy's ndarray.
you can simply apply [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):
`x = np.reshape(x, (1, n))`